# In my C++ code If I print sum outside loop it gives correct answer, but not in any loop for/while, why not?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  long long int first=0,second=1,T,N;     //here T is Number of Cases

  cin>>T;
  long long int fab=first+second;
  long long int sum[T];

  for(long long int i=0;i<T;i++)
  {
    cin>>N;

    while(fab<N)
    {
      first=second;
      second=fab;
      if(fab%2==0)
      {
        sum[i]+=fab;
      }
      fab=first+second;
    }
  }

for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
{
  cout<<sum[i]<<endl;
}
  return 0;
}
```

In the above for loop sum is not providing the correct answer but if sum is used outside for loop then it gives appropriate answer.

Comment: Just a nitpick: VLA's are not standard C++

Comment: I think it's more than a nitpick.  If the OP used the proper C++ constructs, like `std::vector` instead of VLA's, they would not have had a problem and never would have posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
cin >> T;
long long int sum[T];
```

is not valid C++.  An array in C++ must be created using a compile-time expression to denote the number of items, not a variable such as `T`.

The proper construct to use that is standard C++ is `std::vector<long long>`:

```
#include <vector>
//...
cin >> T;
std::vector<long long> sum(T);
```

The code is now standard C++.

The other aspect that this code does is solve the issue brought up in the answer by DietrichEpp, in which you failed to initialize the VLA to 0.  The vector above would have automatically initialized the items to 0 for you.

So the moral of the story is that if you used standard C++, you probably would not have had a problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `sum[T]` variable is not initialized.  You must initialize it:

```
long long sum[T] = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
long long int sum[T];
```

isn't valid C++.

Google for variable length array or dynamic array.  You'll likely see an answer like

```
long long int *sum = new long long int[T].
```

Comment: More likely `std::vector<long long int> sum(T);` Vector's default options will also initialize the the backing array to zero and make OP's problem vanish.

Comment: Indeed, using standard types are good practice.  The original poster will have to learn a bit about include directives and namespaces to use std::vector though.